# Return data from Repository to ViewModel without LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines

I'm just trying to find an answer how to pass the data from `Repository` to `ViewModel` without extra dependencies like `RxJava`. The `LiveData` seems as a not good solution here because I don't need to proceed it in my `Presentation`, only in `ViewModel` and it's not a good practice to use `observeForever`.
The code is simple: I use Firebase example trying to pass data with `Flow` but can't use it within a listener (*Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body* error):

**Repository**

```
    fun fetchFirebaseFlow(): Flow<List<MyData>?> = flow {
        var ret: List<MyData>? = null
        firebaseDb.child("data").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
            object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    val data = dataSnapshot.getValue<List<MyData>>()
                    emit(data) // Error. How to return the data here?
                }

                override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                    emit(databaseError) // Error. How to return the data here?
                }
            })
//        emit(ret) // Useless here
    }
```

**ViewModel**

```
    private suspend fun fetchFirebase() {
        repo.fetchFirebaseFlow().collect { data ->
            if (!data.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                // Add data to something
            } else {
                // Something else
            }
    }
```

Comment: What does it change if `onDataChange` doesn't emit the data (Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body)? How can I change the flow to return the data from here?

Comment: Where do you want to call `fetchFirebase`, in your `ViewModel`?

Comment: I use `viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) { fetchFirebase () }`

Comment: Could use `StateFlow` in your view model and potentially then use `stateIn` to convert from `Flow` being returned from repository.  I'm not fully clear on issue you're seeing but you might also make use of `callbackFlow` in repository.

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly could you explain it in the answer? I made some structure but it also suspends my function like with `callbackFlow` and returns data twice because of initialization.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [callbackFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html)

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    fun fetchFirebaseFlow(): Flow<List<String>?> = callbackFlow {
        
        val listener = object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                val data = dataSnapshot.getValue<List<MyData>>()
                offer(data)
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                
            }
        }
        val ref =firebaseDb.child("data")
        reef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener)

        awaitClose{
            //remove listener here
           ref.removeEventListener(listener)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks good, but my `private suspend fun fetchFirebase() {` is suspended after the first call. What should be added here? 
I mean, if I execute it a couple of times in a loop, the loop executes only once.

Comment: It shouldn't be happening.

Comment: Yes, but it happens in this scenario. If I don't use .collect or use simple flow, all is ok.

Comment: We need to use `close` after `offer` to fix the problem.

Comment: @Psijic closing after the first event will stop the future updates.

Answer (score 0):

[**ObservableField**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableField) is like `LiveData` but not lifecycle-aware and may be used instead of creating an `Observable` object.

```
{
    val data = repo.getObservable()

    val cb = object : Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback() {
        override fun onPropertyChanged(observable: Observable, i: Int) {
            observable.removeOnPropertyChangedCallback(this)
            val neededData = (observable as ObservableField<*>).get()
        }
    }

    data.addOnPropertyChangedCallback(cb)
}


fun getObservable(): ObservableField<List<MyData>> {
    val ret = ObservableField<List<MyData>>()
    firebaseDb.child("events").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
        object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                ret.set(dataSnapshot.getValue<List<MyData>>())
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                ret.set(null)
            }
        })
    return ret
}
```

It is also possible to use [**suspendCancellableCoroutine**](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/suspend-cancellable-coroutine.html) for a single result. Thanks to [Kotlin forum](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/emit-flow-data-from-an-event-listener-function/19916/9).